# string.compareTo(string) not yielding correct results on sort

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, compareto

I have a list view with place distances, as shown below:

```
100
200
300
400
500
50
600
70
40
```

i need to sort this place distances in both ascending and descending order. So wat i did was, sorting the adapter and use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Everything works fine if the distances are 3 digit numbers ie., 230, 450, 352, 254 and so on. But if the place distance is 2 digit like 52, 65, 75 etc, i am getting wrong sorted values as shown below.

for ascending order : after sort i am getting this order

```
100
200
300
400
500
600
50
60
70
```

for descending order : after sort i am getting this order

```
70
60
50
600
500
400
300
200
100
```

my code for sorting is shown below:

```
case R.id.action_sort_dist_fn:

            adapter.sort(new Comparator<Place>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(Place lhs, Place rhs) {
                    return rhs.getPlaceDistance().compareTo(
                            lhs.getPlaceDistance());
                };
            });

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;

        case R.id.action_sort_dist_nf:

            adapter.sort(new Comparator<Place>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(Place lhs, Place rhs) {
                    return lhs.getPlaceDistance().compareTo(
                            rhs.getPlaceDistance());
                };
            });
```

Place.java

```
public class Place {
    String placeName = "";
            String placeDistance="";
            String placeCategoryIcon;

    public Place(String placeName, String placeDistance,
            String placeCategoryIcon) {

        this.placeName = placeName;
        this.placeDistance = placeDistance;
        this.placeCategoryIcon = placeCategoryIcon;
    }

    public String getPlaceName() {
        return placeName;
    }

    public void setPlaceName(String placeName) {
        this.placeName = placeName;
    }

    public String getPlaceDistance() {
        return placeDistance;
    }

    public void setPlaceDistance(String placeDistance) {
        this.placeDistance = placeDistance;
    }

    public String getPlaceCategoryIcon() {
        return placeCategoryIcon;
    }

    public void setPlaceCategoryIcon(String placeCategoryIcon) {
        this.placeCategoryIcon = placeCategoryIcon;
    }

}
```

Comment: Question title is misleading, given the content. Wheres the definition of `Place`?

Comment: @Perception i have added my Place.java. please check for edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the sorting you give is not the actual one you are getting. E.g the second one is actually:

```
70
600
60
500
50
400
300
200
100
```

The comparison shouldn't be done using strings - it compares lexicographically, which means that the comparison is as [described here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29). So "abc" is greater than "ab" and "d" is greater than "ccc".

You want to compare the number values, so please do so. One option is to use `Integer.valueOf` to get the actual integer value equivalents of the values you use.

By the way I see no gain for you to have `placeDistance` a `String` field. Why don't you have it as `Integer` all along?

Answer (score 2):

You're sorting Strings. The natural ordering for String is the lexicographical ordering. What you want is integer ordering. So use an `int` rather than a `String` for `Place.placeDistance`. Or at least transform the strings to compare to integers, and compare those integers.

Also, calling your field `placeDistance` adds unnecessary noise. Just call it `distance` (and do the same for the other fields, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your comparator you use:

```
return rhs.getPlaceDistance().compareTo(lhs.getPlaceDistance());
```

and placeDistance is a string, therefore you are comparing Strings, not numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are comparing strings. try changing your compare override to:

```
@Override
public int compare(Place lhs, Place rhs) 
{
     return Integer.parseInt(rhs.getPlaceDistance()).compareTo(
            Integer.parseInt(lhs.getPlaceDistance()));
};
```

I think the ideal solution might be to hold integers in your place rather than Strings.
Note that if you will have decimal places you should try Float or Double instead of Integer